# “Thou doth protest too much”: changed usage?

Tags: phrase-meaning, figures-of-speech, shakespeare

I remember reading somewhere that the original meaning “thou doth protest too much, methinks” is often used nowadays to take “protest” literally, but this changes its original meaning.  I can’t seem to find where I read this, so I ask here: how has this phrase evolved from its original meaning?

Comment: It should be _Thou dost_ (in the original, it's _The lady doth_).

Comment: Who says it has "evolved"?

Comment: Please add relevant definition/s, linked and attributed, of 'protest' (both senses you mention, if possible). And how does one decide whether a sense of 'protest' is _literal_?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OED

Protest (v.)

> **3.b. intransitive. To make a formal or emphatic declaration or statement.** Now rare or merged in sense 6a.

1603   W. Shakespeare Hamlet iii. ii. 219   *Ham.* Madam, how do you like this play? *Queene* The Lady protests too much.

> *6.a. intransitive. Originally: to make a formal (often written) declaration against a proposal, decision, etc.; to complain, remonstrate. Now usually: to express disapproval or dissent; to object to something. Also in extended use.*